# Implementing copy on write

Tags: c++, copy

How can this be done for a class that holds a generic member, something like:

```
template<typename T> class SP
{
private:
    T* data;
    reference* ref;
    public:
        //Some methods here to access data
};
```

Comment: There are numerous ways to do this and no one "correct" answer.  Consider looking into "Accelerated C++" or "Modern C++ Design" for a discussion on this.

Comment: Are you talking about copy-on-write on fork system call or you are trying to implement a high-level copy-on-write ??

Comment: Fork system (if the method will change the data, create a copy). @templatetypedef, I want A way to do this (as opposed to none, which is what I have now). I do not have those books. I would be happy to look at other questions on SO that relate to this topic, if applicable.

Comment: There are, of course, multiple ways of doing it. But one C++ framework that has spent a significant amount of time improving their architecture, which is heavily based on copy-on-write, is <a href="http://www.qt-project.org/">Qt</a>. See the <a href="https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qshareddatapointer.html">QSharedDataPointer class reference</a> for details. (and, of course, you can always go code-diving too)

Answer (score 1):

I found two different approaches to copy on write (COW):

[COW Poiner](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Copy-on-write)

```
COWPtr<Object> cow(&obj);
const COWPtr<Object> &cow_ref = cow;
std::cout << cow_ref->name; // operator->() doesn't copy the object because its const overload is used
cow->name = "my object"; // here non const operator->() copies the object
(*cow).name // operator*() also copies the underlying object
```

[WRITE method from Adobe stlab](http://stlab.adobe.com/classadobe_1_1version__1_1_1copy__on__write.html)

```
COW<Object> cow(&obj);
std::cout << cow->name; // the object is not copied
cow.write().name = "my object"; // the object is copied here
```